# How to view forks of my plunks?

Tags: plunker

In Plunker how to view forks of my plunks?
I have some plunks that forked, is there a way to see these plunks forks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI does not currently expose the forks of Plunks. This information is, however, recorded and available via the undocumented Plunker api.

To see the forks of a Plunk `<plunkId>`, visit `https://api.plnkr.co/plunks/<plunkId>`. You will see a `forks` property that is an array of the ids of forks.

Comment: it works, a also it provide other information, thank you